# How to fine-tune a RoBERTa Model following HuggingFace tutorial

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-datasets

I'm trying to fine-tune a RoBERTa model for the first time following this [tutorial](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/training#train-with-pytorch-trainer). However, I'm obtaining this error `ValueError: You have to specify either input_ids or inputs_embeds`. I think the problem is because I'm not including the tokenized input.

This is how my code looks so far:

```
tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained('roberta-base')
model = RobertaForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('roberta-base', num_labels=6, problem_type="multi_label_classification")
```

```
import numpy as np
import evaluate

metric = evaluate.load("f1", labels=["Self-direction: action", "Achievement", "Security: personal", "Security: societal", "Benevolence: caring", "Universalism: concern"], average="micro")
```

```
def compute_metrics(eval_pred):
    logits, labels = eval_pred
    predictions = np.argmax(logits, axis=-1)
    return metric.compute(predictions=predictions, references=labels)
```

```
from transformers import TrainingArguments, Trainer

training_args = TrainingArguments(output_dir="test_trainer", evaluation_strategy="epoch")
```

```
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=validation_dataset,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)
```

```
trainer.train()
```

How can I include the tokenizer in the equation and make it work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you creating `train_dataset`? Ideally this data would be tokenized.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things, I would either use RobertaTokenizerFast or AutoTokenizer, not RobertaTokenizer. This will increase your performance.  Then, in your trainer call, you are missing the tokenizer arg.  Assuming you have either `tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(...)` or `tokenizer = RobertaTokenizerFast.from_pretrained(...)`  (NB: they result in the same type of object).  Modify your trainer init call:

```
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=validation_dataset,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)
```

That should solve it.